# Dialog box not renderd properly in android

Tags: android

i have a dialog box, but some how there is an unknown background image. How can i remove that image. Please guide me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extends Dialog Class, build your xml File for your dialog something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you Want to bookmark?" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yes" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

of course you can make some customization

for your custom dialog class you can do like this

```
public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
 Button okButton;

 public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
  super(context);

  /** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the title */
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  yesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_yes);
  yesButton.setOnClickListener(this);

  noButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_no);
  noButton.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.button_yes: 
             dismiss();
             //doSomething
             break;
            case R.id.button_no:
            dismiss();
            //doSomethingElse
            break;

 }

}
```

Hope this will help you
you have to post your code to figure out why these background box appear for you but acting like i mention should resolve the problem for you

Answer (score 1):

That is probably happening because you use the standard `AlertDialog` and set a content view + no title(although you don't set a title the space for it will remain in the dialog).

Extend the `Dialog` class instead and build your dialog like you want. Also if you want to use your own background for the `Dialog` then implement a theme that extends `Theme.Dialog` and override:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/panel_background</item>
```

with your own drawable.